# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '11155111')

Tags: solidity, hardhat, ethereum-wallet-dapp, hardhat-deploy, sepolia

```
PS C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project> npx hardhat deploy --network sepolia
Nothing to compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\deploy\01-deploy-fundme.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '11155111')
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\deploy\01-deploy-fundme.js:19:47)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1055:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1225:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1055:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\BISHOP\Desktop\blockchain_fcc\hardhat-fundme-project\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:669:5)
```

Above mentioned error is coming while deploying to sepolia testnet.
Below provided is the file `01-deploy-fundme.js`

```
//imports
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")
require("dotenv").config()


module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress
    //Should use a mock when going for localhost network or hardhat
    if (chainId === 31337) {
        const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address
    } else {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeed"]
    }

    const args = [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress]
    log("Deploying Fundme contract and waiting for confirmations...")
    const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args, //The Price Feed Address is to enter the constructor in the contract.
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    log(`Fudme contracts deployed at: ${fundMe.address}`)
    log("___________________________________________")

    // await verify(fundMe.address, args)

    if (!chainId == 31337 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        await verify(fundMe.address, args)
    }
}

module.exports.tabs = ["all", "fundme"]
```

Below is the `helper-hardhat-config.js`

```
const networkConfig = {
    31337: {
        name: "localhost"
    },
    11155111: {
        name: "sepolia",
        ethUsdPriceFeed: "0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306",
    },
    // 137: {
    //     name: "mumbai", //Polygon Testnet
    //     ethUsdPriceFeed: "0x0715A7794a1dc8e42615F059dD6e406A6594651A",
    // },
}
const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]


module.export = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}
```

Below is the `hardhat-config.js`

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers")


/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */

const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || ""
const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY

module.exports = {
    solidity: {
        compilers: [{ version: "0.8.18" }, { version: "0.6.6" }],
    },
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
        },
        localhost: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
            chainId: 31337,
        },
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: {
            sepolia: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
        },
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: false,
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        currency: "USD",
        coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
        token: "MATIC",
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
            1: 0, // similarly on mainnet it will take the first account as deployer. Note though that depending on how hardhat network are configured, the account 0 on one network can be different than on another
        },
    },
}
```

Please can someone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution,
The error pops up because in the 01-deploy-fundme.js file, you are accessing `networkConfig`  from helper file which tried to read the network setting for it `11155111` but the `networkConfig`  variable is undefined in the deploy file.

The reason is, in you helper file you are not exporting the variables correctly;

```
module.export = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}
```

it should be `module.exports` not `module.export;`

```
module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
}
```